# How can print a PDF document without prompt?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I need to print a PDF file without prompt in my web application (.NET). Currently using an ActiveX which only support IE, need to use other browsers.

How can I achieve this? is there any options?

Comment: Is the thing you call "printing" really a printout to a sheet of paper or is it a display on the computer screen? If it is the latter one, you could use [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/).

Comment: I can display,i need to take the print out without prompt

Comment: Not possible IMO. Would be a security issue if an arbitrary website could access my printer without my permission.

Comment: Thanks Uwe Keim,but it is possible using Activex in internet explorer!!i want to know is there any common solution for all browsers??